# Factoring $x^2(y+z) + y^2(x+z) + z^2(x+y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariate-polynomial

I have the polynomial
$$x^2(y+z) + y^2(x+z) + z^2(x+y)$$
that I want to factor.

I know how to factor $x^2(y-z) + y^2(z-x) + z^2(x-y)$. Because $(y - z) + (z - x) + (x - y) = 0$, we can use the substitution $(y-z) = -((z-x) + (x-y))$. We get $-x^2(z-x) - x^2(x-y) + y^2(z-x) + z^2(x-y)$. Grouping terms with $(z - x)$ together and terms with $(x - y)$ together, we get $$(y^2 - x^2)(z - x) + (z^2 - x^2)(x - y)$$ Factoring the difference of squares, $$(y - x)(y + x)(z - x) + (x - y)(z - x)(z + x)$$ Factoring out the $(x - y)(z - x)$, $$(x - y)(-y - x)(z - x) + (x - y)(x + z)(z - x) = (x - y)(z - y)(z - x) = -(x - y)(y - z)(z - x)$$

However in the case $x^2(y+z) + y^2(x+z) + z^2(x+y)$, I don't see an easy substitution similar to the one above.

We can use the multi-variable factor theorem, but it takes guessing and I want to avoid guessing. I would like a solid way to factor this.

Comment: Is there some reason to think it factors? Using $y+z=x+y+z-x.$ So this is equivalent to $(x+y+z) (x^2+y^2+z^2)-(x^3+y^3+z^3).$ But $x^3+y^3+z^3$ doesn't have any common factors.

Comment: You don't have to guess. Consider $x^2(y\pm z) + y^2(z\pm x) + z^2(x\pm y)$ as a quadratic in $x$ and calculate its discriminant. For the $"-"$ choice of signs you get a perfect square, and the expression factors nicely. For $"+"$ you don't, and it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for using the word "factoring". The word "factorize" gives me the screaming fantods.

Comment: https://www.edwardgoreyhouse.org/pages/f-is-for-fantods-exhibition

Answer (score 4):

it does not factor at all, as this matrix has full rank:

$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

This is   Corollary 3  on the top of page 213 in Schinzel, *Polynomials with Special Regard to Reducibility*  published 200, Cambridge University Press.  Chapter 3, section 2 is called Theorems of Ruppert.

Also see [Brookfield](http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/%7Ejagy/Brookfield_Factoring_Forms_2016.pdf), although I don't believe he includes this particular result.

Comment: I don't understand what matrices are.